# React native text input synthetic event issue

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have made a reusable textinput component in react native, but when I am trying to access text value it gives me synthetic event object then the text value, I am not able to target text value. I know this maybe a possible duplicate but I have tried many methods but it isn't working. Here is my code snippet.

/**Imported Component **/

```
<InputField
     placeholder="Disabilities"
     defaultValue={values.associatedDisabilities.toString()}
     onChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
/>
```

/**Reusable Component **/

```
<TextInput
          style={[
            styles.textInput,
            props.style,
            { color: theme.colors.mainForeground },
          ]}
          onChangeText={props.onChange}
          defaultValue = {props.defaultValue}
          value={props.value}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          {...props}
          placeholderTextColor={
            currentTheme === ThemeTypes.LIGHT
              ? theme.colors.secondaryText
              : theme.colors.mainForeground
          }
          editable={props.editable}
          selectTextOnFocus={props.editable}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it on the onChange in order to have the value you are looking for:

```
<TextInput
          style={[
            styles.textInput,
            props.style,
            { color: theme.colors.mainForeground },
          ]}
          onChangeText={(value) => props.onChange(value)}
          defaultValue = {props.defaultValue}
          value={props.value}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          {...props}
          placeholderTextColor={
            currentTheme === ThemeTypes.LIGHT
              ? theme.colors.secondaryText
              : theme.colors.mainForeground
          }
          editable={props.editable}
          selectTextOnFocus={props.editable}
/>
```

In second place, you need to control imported comp:

```
<InputField
     placeholder="Disabilities"
     defaultValue={values.associatedDisabilities.toString()}
     onChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
     value
/>
```

Otherwise you can use `event.target.value`, that is the native event value of the input component

Comment: both of them gives same synthetic event object

Comment: can you add a working snippet?

Answer (score 0):

onChange is the internal prop for TextInput, try changing that to some other prop like updateValue={(val) => console.log(val)}

```
<InputField
 placeholder="Disabilities"
 defaultValue={values.associatedDisabilities.toString()}
 // onChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
 updateValue={(value) => console.log(value)}
 />
```